# JSON object issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a variable using data from a JSON file, though it keeps showing as undefined. inspection shows the options object with the following error:

The goal from this code is to configure a product using the first JSON object and then pull in extra information about the product options using the second json object.

The code should output the title of

```
"cover-silk": ["150gsm-silk-cover"]
```

which is stored in the second JSON object

The variable childTitle should = "150gsm"

```js
productData = {
  "product": [{
    "name": "booklet",
    "section": [{
      "coverStock": {
        "cover-silk": ["150gsm-silk-cover"]
      }
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "section2": {
    "coverStock": [{
      "title": "Cover Stock",
      "options": [{
        "cover-silk": {
          "title": "Silk",
          "childOptions": {
            "150gsm-silk-cover": {
              "title": "150gsm"
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
};

var key = productData.product[0].section[0];
var keys = [];
for (var k in key) keys.push(k);

var len = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

var option = productData.product[0].section[0][keys[i]];

  var secObj = (option);
  var secObjArray = [];
  for (var k2 in secObj) secObjArray.push(k2);

  var len2 = secObjArray.length;

  for (var j = 0; j < len2; j++) {

    var childTitle = productData.section2[keys[i]][0].options[0][secObjArray][j].title;
    console.log(childTitle);

  }
};
```

Comment: **title** is a property of **cover-silk**:  productData.section2.coverStock[0].options[0]['cover-silk'].title

Comment: Where's the actual code that throws the error? Take a few minutes to read [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i've updated the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a lot of changes. The whole structure wasn't right. Check out the comments below and working snippet too:

1. The indices are all wrong.
2. The original JSON was wrong.
3. Changed a lot. Better to use Diff.

**Snippet**

```js
var productData = {
  "product": [{
    "name": "booklet",
    "section": [{
      "coverStock": {
        "cover-silk": ["200gsm-silk-cover", "250gsm-silk-cover"],
        "cover-gloss": ["300gsm-gloss-cover", "250gsm-gloss-cover"]
      }
    }],
    "section2": {
      "coverStock": [{
        "title": "Cover Stock",
        "options": [{
          "cover-silk": {
            "title": "Silk",
            "childOptions": {
              "150gsm-silk-cover": {
                "title": "150gsm"
              }
            }
          }
        }]
      }]
    }
  }]
};

var key = productData.product[0].section[0];
var keys = [];
for (var k in key)
  keys.push(k);
var len = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  var option = productData.product[0].section[0][keys[i]];
  var secObj = option;
  var secObjArray = [];
  for (var k2 in secObj)
    secObjArray.push(k2);
  var len2 = secObjArray.length;
  for (j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
    var childTitle = productData.product[0].section[0][keys[i]][secObjArray[j]][0];
    console.log(childTitle);
  }
}
```

**Diff:**

If you are interested, this is the [Diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/U4ntcRr6):

[image: Diff]

Comment: Apologies, I missed that bit whilst trying to simplify the code

.cover-silk is part of the reference [edited question]

Comment: @Nate My answer stays the same. When you want to use a property when it has `-` or some special characters, use the array notation, and not the dot notation. Check my answer.

Comment: My actual code uses array notation:

`childTitle = productData.section2[keys[i]][0].options[0][secObjArray][j];`

It seems to be the .options[0] causing the error

Comment: @Nate Would you like to show us the full code and replicate the error please?

Comment: @Nate You can edit your own question to add the full code. Please do it. `:)` ps: I am also from UK. `:)`

Comment: @Nate Keys is defined wrong. There's no `productData.product`! Check it out.

Comment: @Nate The `var option = productData.product[0].section[0][keys[i]];` shows `undefined`. Also that point of time, `i` is also not defined. It's better we need to sit together to solve this issue. Is it okay to do it tomorrow or do you want it now?

Comment: @Nate Also, at this line `var childTitle = productData.section2[keys[i]][0].options[0][secObjArray][j];` there's no `productData.section2` as it should be `productData.product.section2`.

Comment: I have moved the var childTitle inside the for loop - made errors trying to simplify the code. productData.section2 is the second object in productData

Comment: Really appreciate you looking into this, I'm happy to do whatever you think is best to solve the issue

Comment: @Nate I found the solution. Writing the answer. Please wait.

Comment: @Nate Can you post the right `var product` again? It doesn't seem to be right JSON - check using https://JSONLint.com

Comment: Please forgive me for not being more clear on this, it's my first time using stack overflow.

I have updated the question.

Thanks for the time you have put in to help me with this!

Comment: @Nate Sure. No worries. Hope you are happy with the solution I provided with. `:)`